# Is Landvogt's thesis "The functorial properties of the Bruhat–Tits building" available online?

Tags: reference-request, rt.representation-theory, buildings, functoriality

Universität Münster publishes theses online through "miami", but "miami" doesn't have Erasmus Landvogt's thesis ([search](https://miami.uni-muenster.de/Search/Results?lookfor=Landvogt)).

ProQuest (predatorily) provides many theses, but they don't have Landvogt's ([search](https://www.proquest.com/search/2416530), but apparently you can only save a specific search, not a query, and search links expire?—anyway, the query is `(Erasmus Landvogt) AND stype.exact("Dissertations & Theses")`).

MathSciNet doesn't know about Landvogt's thesis ([search](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/publications-search?query=au%253ALandvogt+pt%253Athesis)).  It does know about his paper [Some functorial properties of the Bruhat–Tits building](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.006), which, based on its title, should be nearly identical; but, in some places (e.g., §1.3.4), the published paper refers to the thesis for details or proofs.  Is the thesis available?

Comment: Here is a link to the thesis' entry on WorldCat, in case it helps: https://www.worldcat.org/title/258622437

Comment: Have you tried interlibrary loan?  In my experience, university librarians are often really good at tracking down documents for you (especially ones that are available in multiple academic libraries, as the WorldCat entry suggests).

Comment: @TheAmplitwist, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450454/is-landvogts-thesis-the-functorial-properties-of-the-bruhat-tits-building-ava#comment1164299_450454), ah, right. I forgot to turn on JavaScript, so it wasn't showing the list.  Since my previous comment is now irrelevant, I have deleted it.

Comment: @AndyPutman, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450454/is-landvogts-thesis-the-functorial-properties-of-the-bruhat-tits-building-ava#comment1164311_450454), good idea.  It hadn't occurred to me, and I have just done so.  (But it would still be nice if there were an online source for people without access to a research library.)

Comment: @LSpice: You could scan it yourself and put it on your website!

Comment: Copying the doi into sci-hub.ru gives me the document (says a friend of mine).

Comment: @AliCaglayan, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450454/is-landvogts-thesis-the-functorial-properties-of-the-bruhat-tits-building-ava#comment1164320_450454), where did your friend find the DOI?  If it's [10.1515/crll.2000.006](https://doi.org/10.1515/crll.2000.006), then that's the Crelle's journal paper.

Comment: @AndyPutman, [re](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450454/is-landvogts-thesis-the-functorial-properties-of-the-bruhat-tits-building-ava#comment1164311_450454), upon being sent the [WorldCat link](https://www.worldcat.org/title/258622437) provided by [@‍TheAmplitwist](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/450454/is-landvogts-thesis-the-functorial-properties-of-the-bruhat-tits-building-ava#comment1164294_450454) in an ILL request, my library concluded that "no library is able to supply this item", and refused the request. 